# using matplot3d objects in 3d space with python, how can it correctly hide some part of object is further away?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d

I use matplot3d(ax.bar3d() and ax.plot) to plot two lines around a cuboid, when looking in bird view[bird view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59BrR.png), this figure shows the read 3d relationship of all the objects. When looking from side[side view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0ye7.png), some part of blue line that behind the green cylinder should be hidden, but this part still can be seen. I tried using parameter alpha, and it failed too. Does any body know how to deal with this ?
My matplotlib version is 2.1.0,  and my python version is 3.4.7

```
# import
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

# global set
XMAX = 4
ZMAX = 15

mpl.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 10
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

print(mpl.__version__)

z = np.linspace(0, ZMAX, 5)
if True:
    arrowstartt = np.zeros((3))
    arrowstartx = np.zeros((3))
    arrowstarty = np.zeros((3))
    arrowendt = np.zeros((3))
    arrowendx = np.zeros((3))
    arrowendy = np.zeros((3))
    arrowcolor= 'black'
    fontsizes = 25
    # x cors
    x = (XMAX + 1) / np.max(z) * z
    y = 0. * z
    zz = 0. * z
    ax.plot(x, y, zz, color=arrowcolor, linewidth=1)
    arrowstartx[0] = x[-1]
    arrowstarty[0] = y[-1]
    arrowstartt[0] = zz[-1]
    ax.text(x[-1], y[-1], zz[-1], "x", color='k', fontsize=fontsizes)
    # y cors
    x = 0. * z
    y = 2 * XMAX / np.max(z) * z
    zz = 0. * z
    ax.plot(x, y, zz, color=arrowcolor, linewidth=1)
    arrowstartx[1] = x[-1]
    arrowstarty[1] = y[-1]
    arrowstartt[1] = zz[-1]
    ax.text(x[-1], y[-1], zz[-1]-1, "y", color='k', fontsize=fontsizes)

    #z cor
    x = 0. * z
    y = 0. * z
    zz = (XMAX) / np.max(z) * z
    ax.plot(x, y, zz, color=arrowcolor, linewidth=1)
    arrowstartx[2] = x[-1]
    arrowstarty[2] = y[-1]
    arrowstartt[2] = zz[-1]
    ax.text(x[-1], y[-1], zz[-1], "z", color='k', fontsize=fontsizes)

    # arrow end
    arrowendx = arrowstartx + [1, 0, 0]
    arrowendy = arrowstarty + [0, 1, 0]
    arrowendt = arrowstartt + [0, 0, 1]

    ax.quiver(arrowstartx, arrowstarty, arrowstartt, arrowendx, arrowendy,     arrowendt,2, color=arrowcolor, linewidth=1)
    # ax.set_xlabel('x')
    # ax.set_ylabel('y')
    # ax.set_zlabe('z')
    # ax.arrow()

''' draw bar as a cylinder '''
if True:
    # draw bar
    xpos = 0.
    ypos = 30.
    dx = 1.4
    dy = 2
    ax.bar3d(xpos, ypos, 0, dx, dy, ZMAX, color='g', zsort='average')
    #ax.bar3d(xpos, ypos, 0, dx, dy, ZMAX, alpha=0.8, color='g',zsort='average')

''' draw two lines'''
if True:
    # the blue line
    y = np.arange(0, 50, 1)
    x = np.ones(len(y)) * (-2)
    z = np.linspace(0, ZMAX, len(y))
    ax.plot(x, y, z, 'b')
    #ax.plot(x, y, z, 'b',alpha=0.8)
    # the red line
    y = np.arange(0, 50, 1)
    x = np.ones(len(y)) * 2
    z = np.linspace(0, ZMAX, len(y))
    ax.plot(x, y, z, 'r')


plt.axis('off')

ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I think that's a general problem in mplot3d

Comment: so currently, in mplot3d it does not do depth detection?